# If two items in basket apply discount - shopping basket price rules in Magento

Tags: magento, discount

I am trying to work out if this is possible with Magento, would assume it is but I can't seem to figure it out.

Essentially what I am trying to succeed in doing is:

If any 2 products added to the cart from category x or y, then apply a 5% discount.

At the moment, all I can work out is how to apply a 5% discount if 2 of the same item are added to the cart.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to figure this out.

If ALL of these conditions are TRUE :

```
If total quantity equals or greater than 2 for a subselection of items in cart matching ALL of these conditions:
    Category is (YOUR CATEGORY HERE)
```